# Python 3.4 not recognizing enter key when executing script

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to execute this command in python3.4:

```
python3.4                       
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> n=int(input("enter a number: ")) 
enter a number: 23
>>> print(n)
23
>>>
```

I have no problems.
But If I put this into a script and then call the script:

```
python3.4 script.py
enter a number: 23^M^M^M^M
```

when I press the enter key I get ^M character instead of the execution of the command.
I tried some script that a month ago were running and encountered the same problem. Any help?

Comment: I have never seen anything like this. What's inside script.py? Also, what distro are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 and the content of the script is                                       n=int(input("enter a number: "))                                                                              print(n)                                                                                                                         the problem could come from that I could have accidentally deleted something from /usr/bin folder in making a desktop icon

Comment: in normal terminal command the enter key works well

Comment: it is not python interpreter fault, seems that something wrong with your shell or terminal newline settings. Maybe you have same problem as here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline

Comment: solved. The problem exists only in my yakuake terminal. If I use standard terminal everithing works!

Answer (score 0):

solved. The problem exists only in my yakuake terminal. If I use standard terminal everithing works!
typing in yakuake

```
 stty sane
```

I solved the problem